# Sort JSON by bool value and title

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sorting

So I have an JSON object being returned by ajax that I need to sort by a meta value of 1 and 0 first then by title keeping the 1's at the top. So essentially I need to sort everything by custom_fields['visitor_bureau'] then by title. I've tried just about everything I can including searching for different sort functions all over the place to get a better idea of how to write this and can't seem to get it right.

I used JSON.stringify() to make the object a string. This is actually a huge JSON object but I just need the 2 fields to sort by. visitor_bureau is boolean and the title can be any string really. This is a horrible description but I am braindead here.

```
{"title":"Some Place","visitor_bureau":"1"}
```

Comment: It's an array of objects, right?

Comment: `"1"` is not a boolean..

Comment: So you show an object? How can an object be sorted? Is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, using the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```js
let array = [{
  "title": "A Some Place",
  "visitor_bureau": "0"
}, {
  "title": "B Some Place",
  "visitor_bureau": "1"
}, {
  "title": "C Some Place",
  "visitor_bureau": "1"
}];

array.sort((a, b) => b.visitor_bureau - a.visitor_bureau || a.title.localeCompare(b.title));

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help that worked like a charm! Learned something new there as I didn't know you could use => with javascript. I use it all the time with PHP but yeah.